# Why is Oracle ADD_MONTHS() returning a different value for sysdate than if I hardcode today's date?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pull all records from 6 months ago up to present.

At first I hardcoded the date for today (Sep 2, 2021) and got the result I expected:

```
select case_no, closed_dt from table1
where closed_dt >= add_months(TO_DATE('09/02/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), -6)
order by closed_dt
```

This gave me the results I wanted, a list of records from Mar 2, 2021, up through today:

```
CASE_NO | CLOSED_DT
-------------------
     94 | 03/02/2021
     57 | 03/03/2021
     29 | 07/26/2021
     04 | 09/02/2021
```

However, this query will be in an automatic script and so I cannot hardcode the date, I need it to dynamically change to always be 6 months in the past.  So I tried to use sysdate, and got this result instead:

```
select case_no, closed_dt from table1
where closed_dt >= add_months(sysdate, -6)
order by closed_dt
```

Result:

```
CASE_NO | CLOSED_DT
-------------------
     57 | 03/03/2021
     29 | 07/26/2021
     04 | 09/02/2021
```

As you can see, the record from Mar 2 is now not getting returned, even though it should be.

Even more confusingly, when I do

```
select add_months(sysdate, -6) from dual
```

It returns `03/02/2021` as expected.

Can anyone explain what is happening, and provide the correct solution to return records from 6 months ago by using sysdate?

Comment: An obvious reason would be time zone issues.

Comment: A much more obvious reason is that `sysdate` has a (generally non-zero) time-of-day component. Your hard-coding would be equivalent to using `trunc(sysdate)`, not `sysdate`, in the call to `add_months()`.

Comment: Can you explain how that would make sysdate appear correct when I select sysdate from dual, but work incorrectly when in a more complex query?

Comment: @mathguy I tried my query using trunc(sysdate) and it now works as expected.  Thank you for your advice.  Please put it in an answer so I can upvote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An Oracle `date` always has a day and a time component.  `TO_DATE('09/02/2021', 'mm/dd/yyyy')` returns a date of 2 September 2021 at midnight.  On the other hand `sysdate` returns the current day and time (2 September 2021 13:51:00 on my local machine).  Assuming the data in your table has a value of 2 March 2021 at midnight, the first query would return the row while the second query would not because of the time.

I'd expect that you want to use the `trunc` function to set the time component to midnight

```
where closed_dt >= add_months(trunc(sysdate), -6)
```